# How to delete all files from "Output" folder using batch script?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a folder structure as below:

```
L:\MyProject\Extract\
                    Activity    Input
                                **output**
                                SSIS
                                Results
                                Headers
                    Account     Input
                                **output**
                                SSIS
                                Results
                                Headers
                    Balance     Input
                                **output**
                                SSIS
                                Results
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

Here, I need to find output folder and delete all files present inside each "output" folder. I am using following script:

```
SET FolderPath=%1

for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`"dir %FolderPath% /ad/b/s output"`) do SET Folder="%%a"
del %Folder%\*.* /Q
```

But using above script, I am able to delete files which are present in "%%a"(last path of output folder). How to do it recursively...? Or is there any array concept to store all paths where **output** folder is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three problems in your code.

First, the `for` loop does not find the `output` subdirs under `FolderPath`, but iterates over all the subdirs of `FolderPath`.

One way to solve this is to specify

```
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`dir "%FolderPath%\output" /ad/b/s`) do
```

Note that I have moved the quotes, just to prepare for the case of names with spaces, which was your second problem. You might further simplify it with

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`dir "%~1\output" /ad/b/s`) do
```

note that `delims` avoids spaces work as delimiters and `%~1` removes the quotes of the parameter

And finally, the `for` loop, in each iteration, just `set`s the `Folder` variable, it does not invoke the `del` command, that is placed outside the loop.

One easy way to solve this problem is to invoke the `del` command on `%%a` without setting the variable `folder`

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`dir "%~1\output" /ad/b/s`) do del %%a\* /q
```

Comment: You should add the option `"delims="` to `for /F` to avoid trouble with paths containing spaces...

Comment: no, I didn't. Read my explanation and you'll understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `find` command to find all subdirectories of the current directory.

To list files in all directories named `Output`:

```
find . -name Output -type d|find -type f -exec ls {} \;
```

To delete all files in directories named `Output`:

```
find . -name Output -type d|find -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: "FIND: parameter format not correct".  Not a valid bat command.

Comment: @PA alright my solution is for the `bash` shell, not for the `DOS` (they both have a find command).

Comment: OP wants a Windows solution, as you can infer by path names, the code posted and the `batch-file` tag.